# Chaining result of a function? Since when is this possible?

Tags: php

I was quite amazed when I erroneously typed what I believed would raise an error:

```
function r() { return array( 'foo' ); }
echo r()[0];
```

To my amazement, it worked and didn't even raise a notice. I remember not being able to do this when I first tried, and I noticed that on Codepad [an error was raised](http://codepad.org/h9Ei0Vly). I am running PHP 5.4.4 and am wondering when this functionality was added and where I can read more about it. Google only showed results for *PHP 5 Method Chaining*, but I suppose this is something else?

Comment: From the [array docs](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php): *"As of PHP 5.4 it is possible to array dereference the result of a function or method call directly. Before it was only possible using a temporary variable."* And you can read more about it there as well (not much, there is nothing special about it actually).

Comment: Thank you, now I can rest assured that I didn't stumble upon some weird bug and leave it like that in my code. ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since PHP 5.4, it's possible to *"array dereference"* the result of a function/method directly; in PHP 5.5, the same goes for an array literal (`array('foo', 'bar')[1];` perhaps even `[1,2,3][1];`, though I'm not sure about the latter)

[See the docs here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php)
Example #7 Array dereferencing:

> As of PHP 5.4 it is possible to array dereference the result of a function or method call directly. Before it was only possible using a temporary variable.
>
> As of PHP 5.5 it is possible to array dereference an array literal.

*edit:*
Just to be clear: method chaining is, indeed, something else; it's often referred to as *"the fluent interface"*, too. At least that's what everybody called it at my previous job. The basic idea is that a method that needn't return anything gets an explicit `return $this;` statement. The upshot is that these methods return a reference to the object, which you can use to invoke another method, without having to type the var a second time:

```
$someObject->setProperty('Foobar')//returns $this
           ->anotherMethod();
//instead of
$someObject->setProperty('Foobar');//returns null by default
$someObject->anotherMethod();
```

The code for this object would look like this:

```
class Foo
{
    private $properties = null;

    public function __construct(array $initialProperties = array())
    {
        $this->properties = $initialProperties;
    }
    //chainable:
    public function setProperty($value)
    {
        $this->properties[] = $value;
        return $this;//<-- that's all
    }
    //NOT chainable
    public function anotherMethod()
    {
        return count($this->properties);//or something
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

[function array dereferencing](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/functionarraydereferencing) was added in version 5.4.0